# QuickTime Plug-In 7.7.2 (in Firefox)

Tags: plugins

QuickTime Plug-In 7.7.2 (in FireFox) shows up in my Applications 32 times.  It seems to me that I shouldn't need but one application and the other 31 are just hogging space.  Is this true?  If so, how do I remove all those QuickTime applications?

Thank you

Comment: I do nto have quicktime installed, but I had similar problems with other plugins which installed with elevated rights and for which I needed to run firefox with elevated rights to uninstalled them. (aka, close firefox.  Start firefox with runas admin, uninstall, close firefox. Start firefox as normal).